# presentShareDialogWithParams does not display the share dialog

Tags: ios, facebook

I am trying to integrate the Facebook Share functionality into an iOS app.  Everything successfully compiles, so the project is set up correctly.  As best as I can tell, I have made the plist updates correctly assuming those are relevant.

I have this...
FBLinkShareParams *params = [[FBLinkShareParams alloc] ... ];

Then I do...
if([FBDialogs canPresentShareDialogWIthParams:params}) { ... }

The above call returns YES/True, and I do get into the "if" logic.  However, this is where the problem exists.

Within the above "if" block I have...
FBAppCall *appCall = [FBDialogs presentShareDialogWithParams:params
                             clientState:nil
                             handler:^(FBAppCall *call, etc... }];

Here is the problem...
I do not see the share dialog, and appCall returns nil here.  Even the documentation says, "A non-nil FBAppCall object is only returned if the corresponding canPresentShareDialogWithParams method is also returning YES for the same params."

Any reason as to why this could possibly return nil when the canPresent returned YES?  Anything I might be missing???

Comment: Native facebook app should be installed on your device to present share dialog

Comment: The Facebook app is installed, and canPresentShareDialogWIthParams would not have returned YES if it weren't installed.

Comment: Is there an app switch at all? Is there any errors returned in the completion handler?

Comment: I do not see any indication of an app switch.  My understanding is that that completion handler just gets call after a share has been made...  as in, after an app switch and the user selects the option to share.  I also added code in the completion handler if there was an error or not, and within there, I added tracing.  I do not see either of those trace statements.